# How to translate the idiomatic expressions "I wish!" and "You wish!"

Tags: traducción, modismos

What's the best way to say "I wish!" as in...

> A: I hear you're a good dancer.
>
> B: Ha! I wish!

Or...

> A: Will you help me move this piano?
>
> B: Ha! You wish!

What is the best way to translate these idiomatic expressions, and their sarcastic tone?

Comment: I think some of the answers don't really consider the sarcastic way you are using these words.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I want to make a note that my answer applies at least for Mexico, it would be:

> I wish! - ¡Ya quisiera!
>
> You wish! - ¡Ya quisieras!

In this case *wish* wouldn't translate as *espero*, but more like *desear* or *querer*.

Comment: I add a little modification to the answer of the 2º question. 


If the meaning that you want to give to the phrase is near to a joke or say to the other person "i dont help you" use "Ya quisieras"

But if you want to say that you want to help and you are happy to help him: "claro ¡cómo quieras!

Comment: _"Eso quisiera"_ and _"Eso quisieras"_ are other ways to say it, too.

Answer (score 17):

For example, in one word I would translate:

> B: Ha! I wish!

into

> B: ¡Ja! ¡Ojalá!

Source: [RAE](http://buscon.rae.es/draeI/SrvltConsulta?TIPO_BUS=3&LEMA=ojal%C3%A1)

Comment: Does this work everywhere or just Mexico? I always mix up *ojalá* and *híjole*...

Comment: "Ojalá" is very common in Spain. In fact, it comes from the arab language, from the times where most of Spain was under muslim rule. There's a nice explanation here: http://etimologias.dechile.net/?ojala.-

Comment: how would you use Ojalá to You wish! though?

Comment: @Rafael.IT you can't translate You wish! with ojalá. Thats why I just put I whish.

Comment: I see.. is still a good answer, thanks for that!

Answer (score 3):

Besides what others have written, I'd add these two translations:

> *I wish!* = ¡Ya me gustaría!
>
> *You wish!* = ¡Ya te gustaría!

Answer (score 1):

> A: I hear you're a good dancer.
>
> B: Quisiera serlo
>
> A: Will you help me move this piano?
>
> B: Si es lo que quieres

'Espero' is more as 'wait' than 'wish'.  'Quiero' is more realted with 'wish' and 'need'

Comment: I believe the second use of `You wish` is meant to be sarcastic.  So in the case of `Si es lo que quieres` (If that's what you want), you'd want to say the opposite of that.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off saying "en tus sueños" as a form of saying "you wish".

It translates from "in your dreams" directly.

Comment: I don't know why this answer got three downvotes.  I have upvoted.

Answer (score 0):

"I wish!" to show disbelief:

> A: Juan me dijo que bailas muy bien. [Juan told me you're a very good dancer.]
>
> B: ¡Ya mero!  Pues no.  Seguro que te estaba tomando el pelo. [Yeah, right. Well, no.  He must have been pulling your leg.]

"You wish!" to show rejection:

> A: Me ayudas a pasar este piano para otra parte? [Will you help me take this piano somewhere else?]
>
> B: ¡¿Cómo crees?!  [Wait, what?!  Dream on!]

Both of these expressions, "ya mero" and "Cómo crees" are nice and sarcastic.  Another good sarcastic expression of disbelief is "Ay sí" [*Yeah, sure*], which  doesn't work very well in print, because the sarcasm comes across primarily from the tone of voice.